# How to prevent creating duplicate web-sockets in redux-observable

Tags: websocket, redux, rxjs, observable

I'm using redux-observable with RxJS 5 in my project. For some reason, this epic will create duplicate websocket if 'START_STREAM' action was dispatched before 'CLOSE_STREAM' was dispatched. Is there any method to check if there is any connected websocket?

```
import { WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject';

const fetchStreamEpic = (action$, store) => action$
  .ofType('START_STREAM')
  .mergeMap(
    () => {
      const socket$ = WebSocketSubject.create(`wss://somepath/ws/v1/`);
      return socket$.multiplex(
        () => console.log('subscribe'),
        () => console.log('unsubscribe'),
        () => true,
      );
    },
  )
  .takeUntil(action$.ofType('CLOSE_STREAM'))
  .map(msg => ({ type: 'RECEIVE_DATA', payload: msg }))
  .repeat();

export default fetchStreamEpic;
```

Comment: [`distinctUntilChanged`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html) will do the trick, but only superficially. Do you need to do something if you get two `START_STREAM`s in a row?

Comment: @concat If there is a websocket connected, `START_STREAM` should not create another websocket.